# updating html elements on page without post back

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, browser

I am dynamically generating html in javascript. my html is following

```
<table id="tr1">
 <tbody>
 <tr><td><img src="D:\listhell\adimg\autos\76cecc74-733d-4794-af6c-caca4d0bfd45.jpg" style="width:50px;"></td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="D:\listhell\adimg\autos\a84b01e3-7811-4897-8e4b-fa351ddd4aca.jpg" style="width:50px;"></td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="D:\listhell\adimg\autos\02ab6f2d-5a26-40a6-bcef-a18ce10dd14d.jpg" style="width:50px;"></td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="D:\listhell\adimg\autos\c47516b8-c265-4d68-a41c-fc74ade50ab7.jpg" style="width:50px;"></td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="" style="width:50px;"></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

I am generating it using javascript like this

```
  function uploadComplete() {
        var v = $.cookie("path").split(',');
        for (i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {

            $("#tr1").append("<tr><td><img src='" + v[i] + "' style='width:50px;' /></td></tr>");

        }
        alert("completed");


    }
```

the uploadComplete() is a javascript event and it occurs when the file(s) get uploaded using ajax fileupload control.

The problem is in Chrome the html gets generated and I see it using inspect element but in browser UI it's not displaying. And in firefox the table get displayed in browser's ui but images are not getting loaded.

Any advise, opinion, suggestion will be helpful,thanks

Answer (score -1):

You will have to do this:

```
$("#tr1 tbody").append("<tr><td><img src='" + v[i] + "' style='width:50px;' /></td></tr>");
```

You need to append rows to tbody and not directly inside table

Comment: I do not see anything wrong with this code. The only reason you are not able to see things correctly could be because of the faulty markup being rendered on the page. Please check you markup carefully. You must be missing something there.

Answer (score -1):

Try This :

```
$('#tr1 tr')
   .last()
   .after("<tr><td><img src='" + v[i] + "' style='width:50px;' /></td></tr>");
```

Comment: I can see the html in source that rows are inserted but it's not reflecting in browser screen

Comment: check your image path .. can you access these images..?

Comment: are you getting the alert completed ?

Comment: Your image should be on a relative path not absolute one.

Say your html file is in D:\myhtml\home.html. Copy the Images folder in myhtml. Then change your code to <img src="Images\TechnipLogo.jpg" >

Hope this helps

Comment: OK i changed it to relative path. Now it's showing img placeholder but not showing image itself

Comment: i think still your path is not correct, can you edit your question with new src path.

Comment: ok I posted respective Q http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27720457/img-not-loading-image-using-ajax-call